# Schedule AsyncTask to run every minute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, scheduled-tasks

What is the best practice to schedule an `AsyncTask` to have it run every minute (note that after the AsyncTask has finished I should be able to update the UI).

I'm not intending on using a `Service` because these tasks should only run when app is active.

EDIT: What the AsyncTask is just downloading JSON data from a webserver (which I need to update UI). The JSON data is pretty small a couple of kilobytes.

Comment: you can do the same with even service, just stop it when you don't need it! Use alarm manager to schedule it after every 5 minutes, that's the best practice so far

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `Timer` object.

There's a full example:

```
public class TimerActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();

    myTimer.schedule(myTask, 3000, 1500);
  }

  // In this class you'd define an instance of your `AsyncTask` 
  class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    MyAsyncTask atask;

    final class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Param1, Param2, Param3> {
      // Define here your onPreExecute(), doInBackground(), onPostExecute() methods
      // and whetever you need
      ...
    }

    public void run() {
      atask = new MyAsyncTask<Param1, Param2, Param3>();
      atask.execute();
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What is `TimerScheduleFixedRate` ?

Comment: It would be a class extending a `TimerTask` where inside you would define your `AsyncTask`, and anything related to it handling.

Comment: Can you show some short code sample for that class and how does the `run()` method work?

Comment: I've added a complete example, hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks but why do you need to extend `TimerTask`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you **have** to, but when you define the `.schedule()` call you're passing it a `Timer` which will run the `run()` method of the `TimerTask`, so I think this is the easiest way, don't know if that's the only one though.

Comment: Sure, in fact, it's intended for this. You can update the UI from this method.

Comment: Alright because I read something about when using a `Timer` or `TimerTask` you can't update the UI?

Comment: You can, but not directly. I'd suggest using a `Handler` or a `BroadcastReceiver`. In the Android reference there are several good examples on how to use them if you haven't yet, just have a check or find the corresponding example at `Vogella`.

Comment: Though it seems to work for me? `onPostExecute` is called from the main thread and then in `onPostExecute` I do this: `MapFragment mapFragment = weakMapFragment.get(); if (mapFragment != null) { mapFragment.updateTrackedPerson(result); }` Maybe I shouldn't worry about it if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `Timer`:

`timer.schedule(asyncTask, 0, 50000); //execute in every 50000 ms`

You can update your UI in the `onPostExecute()` overrided method of the `AsyncTask` class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html