# Asynctask with timer. Will it run even if the app is not running in the background?

Tags: android

I want to update my database on the server (using 000webhost) every 15 minutes, I searched and found aysnc task + timer will do what I need but I am not sure will it update my database even if the application is not running on the android device? Can anybody clear this doubt for me?
This is what i will follow to do my task:
     [Schedule AsyncTask to run every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040049/schedule-asynctask-to-run-every-minute)
Also will this be the correct approach?

Comment: Why do you want to update the database when the app is not running?  If it's not running, will there be any data to update?

Comment: please follow this link http://www.codeitive.com/0SyjqVWWWP/async-task-stopped-when-app-terminates-ondestroyed-is-called.html  to clear this doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this approach will work even if your app is not running. But if your app is not running, why would you use an `AsyncTask`? The idea of the `AsyncTask` is that it provides handy methods to do some work in the background and easy post results on the UI thread afterwords. If your app is not running you don't need the second part.

So a better solution for you would be to use the combination of `Timer` and `IntentService`. The former starts the latter which does the heavy-lifting (in your case update the database) and you're all done.

Lastly I would suggest you to take a look at the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) class. If it's not really critical to run your task every 15 minutes it's much better for the device's batter to use this one.

Comment: Look out: with the job scheduler you can run task for 60 seconds before the system ask you to shutdown your service. This time is not documented.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response. Actually I want to fetch the current location  (lat and lng) of the device and check if there is a change in location (which should be checked every 15 min) then update the database on server. For doing this what approach would be best suited?